# ASP.NET Core 3 How do I call cotroller from another class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'd like to call a method of controller in a normal class, not a controller.
However, the creator of APIController does not know how to call because it requires context.
How can I call a controller that uses DBContext in the class?

**APIController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;

    public APIController(ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [Route("API")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResultIEnumerable<CommonCode>>> WantCallThis()
    {
        return await _context.CommonCode.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use .net core or autofac dependency injection for create object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more read about how working with DI (dependency injection).
[Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
or [ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection Best Practices, Tips & Tricks](https://medium.com/volosoft/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-best-practices-tips-tricks-c6e9c67f9d96)
I use in my projects [autofac](https://autofac.org/).
If you work with ASP .Net Core, you need to add in registration in Startup.cs your new class, such as

```
 services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
```

Good luck!